# Copy-Item is not working for destination having whitespace in the path variable

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to run the below powershell script from the PowerGUI editor

```
$windowsServicePath = (gwmi win32_service|?{$_.name -eq "Test Windows Service"}).pathname

$windowsServicePath = $windowsServicePath.Replace("\TestWindowService.exe","")

Write-Host $windowsServicePath

$source = "C:\\Temp\\Configs\\App.DEVINT.config"

Copy-Item -path "$source" -destination $windowsServicePath -recurse -verbose;
```

On running the above powershell script using the PowerGUI I am getting the below error:

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.
At C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Powershell Details\Automation Scripts\Test-Powers.ps1:41 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  -path "$source" -destination $windowsSerivcePath -recurse -verbose;
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

The `$windowsServicePath` value is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\TestWindowsService`

But if I update the `Copy-Item` command with the below code then it works for me

```
Copy-Item -path "$source" -destination "C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\TestWindowsService" -recurse -verbose;
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `$windowsServicePath` value is actually `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\TestWindowsService"` (with quotes). Can you remove them and pass that to `Copy-Item`